# Complexity of Unknotting problems

Tags: reference-request, cg.comp-geom, topology

The complexity of the Unknotting problem is known to be in $\mathrm{NP} \cap\mathrm{co\text-NP}$, see references:

1. [The Computational Complexity of Knot Problems.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807016)
2. [Knottedness is in NP, modulo GRH.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.0845) .
3. [Unknotting is in $\mathrm{AM}\cap\mathrm{co\text-AM} $](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/1070432.1070482).

Some even believe the problem to be in $P$, but to relax the ptime constraints, due to (maybe) either the cost, or diagram of the knot. It maybe there exists an Arthur-Merlin type protocol for unknottedness. This could lead to possibly interesting applications too. Also, if Unknottedness is $\mathrm{NP}$ -complete then the polynomial hierarchy collapses.

But  by relaxing the ptime constraints to a quasipolynomial one leads one to quasipolynomial time algorithm for Unknotting. Is there any such quasipolynomial time algorithm for Unknotting?

What (if any) would be the implications of such a quasipolynomial algorithm be to other conjectures such as GRH(?), ETH, or even SETH?

Comment: Knottedness is in NP without the need for GRH: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.00290

Answer (score 9):

Such a quasi-polynomial algorithm has just been claimed by Marc Lackenby from Oxford University. He will present in next Tuesday (02 Feb 2021) in a Zoom talk: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/research/seminars/?talk_id=6082

Answer (score 3):

The outline from Marc Lackenby's talk about a quasipolynomial algorithm for Unknottedness.
 [Unknot recognition in quasipolynomial time outline.](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lackenby). Under the talks section there are slides about the algorithm.

And for the seminar video, which has been uploaded link  [to the video and more about the result.](https://video.ucdavis.edu/media/quasipolynomial-unknot/1_w3i5jvqi) .

Comment: For those who might have difficulties with following arguments involving Heegard splittings and incompressible (incomprehensible?) surfaces... Here is also a short announcement of the talk by the university in layman's terms, with some historical background on the problem: https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/38304